# How to find URL of YouTube video being played by an Android app?

Tags: video, networking, network-monitor, youtube, android-app

An app I use plays some YouTube videos, which are probably unlisted videos. Is there any way using network monitoring etc to identify the URL being accessed so that after copying that URL the particular video can be directly accessed on YouTube?